# Add "get formula" function in Mac excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to realize the get formula function
I put the following in Visual Basic Editor

```
Function getformula(r As Range) As String
  Application.Volatile
  If r.HasArray Then
  getformula = "<-- " & " {" & r.FormulaLocal & "}"
  Else
  getformula = "<-- " & " " & r.FormulaLocal
  End If
End Function
```

But it doesn't work and shows "NAME" error

Comment: Have you put it in a module?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Did you place the code in a module *that you inserted*? Check [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/386648-getformula-question.html). Your Sub works ok for me, Office 2010, Win 7. Please post your versions, that may be useful for anyone trying to help.

Comment: Why would that need to be volatile if the range is being passed into it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things and turned out that the formula name is case-sensitive (However, I'm not sure). Using `GETFORMULA` instead of `getformula` works for me in Excel 2022.

```vb
Function GETFORMULA(r As Range) As String
Application.Volatile
If r.HasArray Then
    GETFORMULA = "<-- " & " (" & r.FormulaArray & ")"
Else
    GETFORMULA = "<-- " & " " & r.FormulaArray
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Function getformula(r As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    If r.HasArray Then
    getformula = "<-- " & _
     " {" & r.FormulaLocal & "}"
    Else
    getformula = "<-- " & _
    " " & r.FormulaArray
    End If
End Function
```